# Error while running Fastlane resign command Print: Entry, ":CFBundleDisplayName", Does Not Exist

Tags: fastlane, cfbundledisplayname

When I am trying to resign the unsigned IPA file, I am facing below issue while running below fastlane command.
I am also using "CFBundleDisplayName" key and string in info.plist file
Command: fastlane sigh resign <ipa-filename.ipa> --signing_identity --provisioning_profile

Error:
15:43:12 Print: Entry, ":CFBundleDisplayName", Does Not Exist
15:43:12 cp: _floatsignTemp/Payload/<app_name>.app/embedded.mobileprovision: No such file or directory
15:43:12 _floatsignTemp/Payload/<app_name>.app: replacing existing signature
15:43:12 _floatsignTemp/Payload/<app_name>.app: errSecInternalComponent
15:43:12 Encountered an error, aborting!
15:43:12
15:43:12 [15:43:12]: Something went wrong while code signing <ipa_file_name>.ipa
15:43:12
[2022-02-06T21:43:12.218Z] [!] Failed to re-sign .ipa

Can anyone please let me know what exactly I am missing ?

Comment: I tried it in a different node and it signed fine. I am guessing an issue with keychain!?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the *.ipa you are trying to resign doesn't contain the "Bundle display name" key into its plist.
You can check and solve that by doing those steps:

1. Renaming your *.ipa into *.zip
2. Unzip it and go into the "payload" folder
3. Right click "show package content" on the *.app
4. Select the info.plist and open it with xCode => here, you can check there is no "Bundle display name"
5. Add the key "Bundle display name" and assign a value to it.
6. Save the plist, rezip the "payload" folder and change the extension to *.ipa
7. Try to resign this new ipa